# QTP - if object exists in object repository

Tags: vbscript, qtp

In QTP is there any way in the code to check to see if a specific object exists in the object repository. I have tried the following code:

```
If JavaWindow(className).JavaDialog(dialogName).Exist Then
    doThisStuff
Else
    doThisStuffInstead
End If
```

But from what I have gleamed from the Internets, this is similar to a isVisible method, only resulting in true if the specified object is currently visible. When I use the above code I receive a "JavaDialog object was not found in the Object Repository." Is there a method or any way to prevent this very error and check to see if the object does indeed exist?

Thank you for your time

Comment: What does `className` and `dialogName` refer to? Are those *both* names to objects present in your object repository or are you using [Descriptive Programming](http://mercuryquicktestprofessional.blogspot.nl/2006/11/descriptive-programming-simplified.html)?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I was trying to create a method where sometimes the variable className had a dialog and sometimes it didnt. I figured out something similar to the checked answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, one typically knows if an object exists in the object repository before using it. The doubt is usually whether there is a corresponding control in the AUT (Application Under Test).

If you really face the situation that sometimes the object is in the repository and sometimes it isn't (I can think of several ways for this to happen but none of them make much sense) then you can use VBScript's [error handling mechanism](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/08/19/error-handling-in-vbscript-part-one.aspx).

```
On Error Resume Next ' Turn off error handling
' Just check if object is in repository, there's no need to do anything with it
Dim Exists: Exists=JavaWindow(className).JavaDialog(dialogName).Exist
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    doThisStuff 'Exists is still empty
Else
    doThisStuffInstead ' Exists is properly set
End If
On Error Goto 0 ' Resume regular error handling
```

Comment: Hope ya fine with my edit. If not, undo it. (I´ll delete this comment later.)

Comment: And it might be a better demo if you declare Exists before the on error resume next, do the on error goto 0 immediately after the Exist call, and then branch depending on IsEmpty (Exists). This would make sure doThisStuff and DoThisStuffInstead will be called with error handling enabled, which is a good idea for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

So, from the error you get, either the dialog that appears is different from the one you've stored in the repository or you don't have it there. 
Have you checked it is really present in the Repository? You can try to just locate this element button. 
Using the method of "if object not in the repository - skip the step" is not really a good idea. 1. Why would you want to skip the test/part of the test if the object was not saved in the repository?
2. If it's not there, so you need to make sure to store it.

I would assume that this "missing" object might have some values by which it's matched to the object from the repository different from test to test. You can tune the "matching" mechanism by manually setting the values by which you want QTP to locate it.